# Difference between @objc, @class_protocol and :class in swift Swift

Tags: swift

What's the difference between:

1. `@objc protocol name {}`
2. `@class_protocol protocol name {}`
3. `protocol name: class {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Obj-C compatible protocol (can be adopted only by classes, can contain optional methods, you can check dynamically whether a class conforms to that protocol).
2. Protocol that can be adopted only by classes (deprecated syntax)
3. Protocol that can be adopted only by classes (new syntax)